# Is the the %[^\n] conversion specifier not compatible with structures?

Tags: c

[image: My Code im trying to solve]

So, im trying to use this specifier with structures but when i type user input wth spaces and dots, the code breaks and ends. For example, im trying to type "L. A." in the name.middleInitial but my code keeps breaking when i do that.

I tried using `[^\n]` with a normal character variable and it worked but does it not work with structures?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't post images of code. Copy-paste the code as *text* into the question instead.

Comment: As for the problem, add a space before the format specifier.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: An MCVE would answer the questions: How is your struct defined? What type is middleinitial? What is mtial? What compiler warnings do you get? (Though that one should be given by you directly, too.)

Comment: What return values do you get from your scanf calls? Ignoring them is a necessary part of not finding most input-related errors.

Comment: If you have run a test where the only difference was whether a variable was inside a `struct` or not, and got different results, then almost certainly your code is exhibiting some form of **undefined behavior**. We may be able to be more specific if you cut and past your code (as text, not an image).

Answer (score 0):

scanf has no particular relation with structs.
@Cool Guy is right: a space would help.
It would be helpful to have code, not a picture of it and the exact account of error.

Simplest possible code that replicates the error is often your first step in debugging.
fgets() is more useful and secure.
Following basic code shows scanf being used with structs.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct myinfo
{
    char firstName[20];
    char address[20];
    unsigned int age;
};
typedef struct myinfo Myinfo;
// -----------------------------

void print_myinfo(Myinfo* m);

// -----------------------------

int main()
{
    Myinfo m;

    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", m.firstName);

    printf("Address: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", m.address);

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &m.age);

    Myinfo* ptr_myinfo = &m;
    print_myinfo(ptr_myinfo);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// -----------------------------
void print_myinfo(Myinfo* m)
{
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("First Name: %s\n", m->firstName);
    printf("Address   : %s\n", m->address);
    printf("Age: %d\n", m->age);
}
```

Output (The 's' in the scanf format specifier is not necessary)

---

```
    Enter first name: one two
    Address: three four 124
    Age: 65536
    -----------------------------------
    First Name: one two
    Address   : three four 124
    Age: 65536

    Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 13.803 s
    Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i realized that i needed a space before the %[^\n]